# symfony/encore @babel/preset-env right way to set corejs

Tags: php, symfony, babeljs, webpack-encore

after `@babel/preset-env` update to version `7.4.2` I had error:

```
WARNING: We noticed you're using the `useBuiltIns` option without declaring a core-js version. Currently, we assume version 2.x when no version is passed. Since this default version will likely change in future versions of Babel, we recommend explicitly setting the core-js version you are using via the `corejs` option.

You should also be sure that the version you pass to the `corejs` option matches the version specified in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` section. If it doesn't, you need to run one of the following commands:

npm install --save core-js@2 npm install --save core-js@3
yarn add core-js@2 yarn add core-js@3
```

and the only working solution I have found was to set like so in my `weback.config.js`

```
Encore.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
    babelConfig.presets[0][1].corejs = 2;
}, {});
```

but I do not like to set in `[0][1]` to add new property to preset-env array.. 
Maybe have more suggestions how to do in right way?

Comment: looks like this could be an issue with one of your dependencies, have a look at this report: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9751